# Android: Record video in memory but don't store it

Tags: android

I want to build a recording app that will record for couple of seconds but don't save the video on the storage device. For example i record a 2 seconds video, than record a 3 seconds video and only when i press the save button the 2 videos will get merged and saved into storage. Is that possible? To save those video on the RAM probably?
I just don't want those videos to be seen on the storage device unless they explicitly save them.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. Why are you trying to do this? I'm not saying don't explore this interesting question, but I am advising you consider the consequences.

Comment: Because if they quit the app they will end up with some random videos on the storage device. Or it is possible to hide them?

Comment: I am not aware of a way to have `MediaRecorder` record to memory, instead of disk. "I just don't want those videos to be seen on the storage device unless they explicitly save them" -- then record them to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: Delete unsaved videos on exit.

Comment: Idea: When a user is recording several hours every day, the storage could have a longer lifetime, if only some recordings will be saved to storage and the rest would cycle in RAM (for example by cycle recording).